# shm_open is an undefined symbol in shared library

Tags: linux, linker, shared-libraries, shared-memory, glibc

I compiled a object file `shm.o` and packaged it as a shared library `libshm.so`

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -fPIC -o shm.o -c shm.c
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -shared shm.o -o libshm.so -lrt
```

where `shm.c` and output of `nm libshm.so` are shown as follow.

```
/*shm.c*/

#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void func_shm(void)
{
    int ret = shm_open("/test_shm", O_CREAT, 0644);
}



/*output of nm*/

00000328 t $a
000002e4 t $a
00000484 t $a
...
...
00000328 t call_weak_fn
0001102c b completed.10740
         w __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.4
...
...
0000034c t deregister_tm_clones
000003e0 t __do_global_dtors_aux
00010f0c t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
00011028 d __dso_handle
00010f10 a _DYNAMIC
00000484 t _fini
00000448 t frame_dummy
00010f08 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
00000498 r __FRAME_END__
0000044c T func_shm
00011000 a _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
         w __gmon_start__
000002e4 t _init
         w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
         w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
00000390 t register_tm_clones
         U shm_open@@GLIBC_2.4
0001102c d __TMC_END__
```

As it can see, at the second line to last, `shm_open` is a undefined symbol even though `-lrt` is appended.

As per [shm_open(3) — Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html); However, the version of glibc shown in the `nm` is 2.4.

> These functions are provided in glibc 2.2 and later.

My expectation are

1. `libshm.so` will have a definition of
   `shm_open`, because `-lrt` is appended at the end of command; Therefore `shm_open` will not be an undefined symbol.
2. Any application that invokes `func_shm` only needs to link to
   `libshm.so` without specifying `-lrt`

What should be done to get this problem fixed?

Comment: Try using -lpthread along with -lrt.

Comment: Tried. Whether `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -shared shm.o -o libshm.so -lrt -lpthread` or `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -shared shm.o -o libshm.so -lpthread -lrt`, still undefined symbol.

Comment: You might try posting the original error message. I'm still not sure if this is a link-time problem you are having, or a runtime problem -- i.e. dlopen().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As it can see, at the second line to last, shm_open is a undefined symbol even though -lrt is appended.

This is *expected*: you are linking against `librt.so`. The *definition* of `shm_open` is in `librt.so`, and *not* in your library.

> My expectation is that after linking process, libshm.so will have a definition of shm_open, so shm_open should not be an undefined symbol.

This expectation is wrong.

What you described is what would have happened if you linked with `librt.a` (archive library). In that case, the linker would have pulled the object implementing `shm_open()` into `libshm.so`.

But since you are linking against `librt.so` (which provides the definition), the linker simply records that `librt.so` is required at runtime, and that `shm_open()` will need to come from some external shared library at runtime. The reference to `shm_open()` in `libshm.so` remains unresolved.

> In addition, any application that invokes func_shm only needs to link to libshm.so without specifying -lrt

This is *indeed* what should already happen (provided you link `libshm.so` against `-lrt`, like your command line shows).

If the application itself doesn't call anything from `librt.so`, and only calls `func_shm()`, then linking it with `gcc main.o -L/... -lshm` should work.

I tried this on Linux/x86_64, and it worked:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -o libshm.so shm.c -lrt

# Verify that libshm.so requires librt.so:
readelf -d libshm.so | grep NEEDED
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [librt.so.1]

gcc main.c -L. -lshm
# success
```

Now, you might be confused because the application linked as above will not actually run:

```
./a.out
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libshm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But that is an entirely different problem -- the application doesn't know which directory to find `libshm.so`. To fix this, add `-Wl,-rpath=/path/to/dir` (which `/path/to/dir` is the directory in which `libshm.so` is to be found at runtime).

Comment: I edited the question to make it slightly different from the original one. Can you please add something more concrete to this answer to make it perfect?